# duplicate result to extract data from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, foreach, jquery-append

i´m traying to extract data from my array and append this data to span.

i´m working with laravel and blade

first i´m doing loop to get data from one array and create div and span in this div:

```
@foreach ($status as $sta)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $sta }}:</span><span class="porcentaje ml-2"></span>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

after i´m doing loop in jquery to other array that contain value for status:

```
<script>
        let total = {!! json_encode($totalCall) !!};
        
        $.each(total, function(valor, indice) {
            $(".porcentaje").text(valor);
        });
        
    </script>
```

**total** it´s array that contain this values:

```
[3, 3, 4, 3]
```

but when i do text in my span i´m getting this:

```
AUSENTE:3
CONFIRMADA:3
NUEVA:3
NULA:3
```

this it´s differents status and i need append this data in this status. I don´t know that i´m doing wrong.

Thanks for help me and read me. Sorry for my english

Comment: `$(".porcentaje")` selects _all_ the elements with that class across the whole document, so you are setting the text content for all of them each time. Use https://api.jquery.com/eq/ to only pick the element matching your each index variable.

Comment: You are updating `span id ='porcentaje'` by looping `total`. First time you set its text as `3`, then `3`, `4` and lastly again to `3`. So Its text is `3`

Comment: @navnath thaks for your response. How i can to do this¿?

Comment: thanks for your response, but i´m creating any span with this class in @foreach and i have all status in this for-each and i need value in this status. not set one to one

Comment: @scorpions78 you just need to do `$(".porcentaje").eq(indice).text(valor);`

Comment: @navnath set value only last element

Comment: @scorpions78 Do you got the solution. Or else what is the intention behind using js to set total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the statuses and the totals all correspond, which it looks like they do, then why have two separate loops? Just output the totals as you go through your statuses?

```
@php $i = 0; @endphp
@foreach($status as $sta)
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $sta }}:</span><span class="porcentaje ml-2">{{ $totalCall[$i] }}</span>
    </div>
    @php $i += 1; @endphp
@endforeach
```